# Metamask retrieve next transaction nonce

Tags: metamask, javascript, nonce

I am testing a smart contract that requires a nonce for every single method I invoke.
My idea was to use the Metasmask transaction nonce of the connected account, but I do not know how to extract the nonce of the next transaction from javascript... is there a built-in api method I can call that returns it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nonce is just a number of previous transactions you made with your account. Every new transaction requires nonce to prevent double-spending attacks. You can read more about it [here](https://kb.myetherwallet.com/en/transactions/what-is-nonce/).

There is a [function](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#gettransactioncount) in web3 API for retrieving nonce.